# combining counts by type

Tags: single-word-requests

Automated word counting is often performed in parallel, resulting in multiple counts for a given word, which need to be summed in post processing; this is similar to the binning process of building a histogram. The best word I can think of for this word-by-word combining of counts is aggregation. Someone else used collate but that doesn't seem to fit. Can you think of a better word or word pair?

Comment: This is typically called MapReduce

Comment: You'd likely find a better word in an AI/ML forum. And context matters greatly, so you'll need to include an example sentence. Fields have jargon that you'll want to use to encourage understanding.

Comment: @DanBron we are indeed implementing MapReduce, where words like combine have very specific meaning. Looking for a synonym that's more general here (if such a thing exists).

Comment: In philosophy, we talk about the distinction between by 'type' and 'token'.  So if someone says "most children hear three million words by the age of three", I might ask:  "Do you mean type or token?"  A 'type' count will produce the smaller number, for the reason you have already mentioned.  The sample sentence, was (obviously) a count by token, with every instance of 'the', 'and', 'a' etcetera  counted.  In general, word counts for editorial purposes are token counts, because they relate to the LENGTH of a text.  But the the number of words I know is a type count

Comment: @Tuffy I'm guessing you'll find this interesting: https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/tokenization-1.html

Comment: @Jason Thank you, Jason.  It is interesting, though that sense of ‘tokenisation’ is not what the questioner seems to have in mind.